# ! grep in R - finding items that do not match

Tags: r

I want to find rows in a dataframe that do not match a pattern.

```
 Key = c(1,2,3,4,5)
 Code = c("X348","I605","B777","I609","F123")
 df1 <- data.frame(Key, Code)
```

I can find items beginning with I60 using:

```
 df2 <- subset (df1, grepl("^I60", df1$Code))
```

But I want to be able to find all the other rows (that is, those NOT beginning with I60).  The invert argument does not work with grepl.  grep on its own does not find all rows, nor can it pass the results to the subset command.  Grateful for help.

Comment: `subset(df1, !grepl("^I60", Code))`

Comment: Not sure what you mean that `grep` doesn't work. `df1[grep("^I60", df1$Code, invert = TRUE), ]` or `df1[-grep("^I60", df1$Code), ]` seems to work fine. I also never understood why would someone use `subset`. It is always reminds me this strange urge people have to use `plyr` for some reason.

Comment: Fair point, just (bad) habit, but I'm new to R.   Thanks for your comments, appreciated.

Comment: Upvote for use of 'invert' there - for some reason that flag had escaped me when using grep. Neat. Also works well when combining with pipe to exclude multiple objects.

eg df1[grep("^I60|^F123", df1$Code, invert=TRUE, ]

Comment: which(!grepl()) gives you the inverse of grep()

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `[` operator and do

```
df1[!grepl("I60", Code),]
```

(Suggested clarification from @Hugh:) Another way would be

```
df1[!grepl("I60",df1$Code),]
```

Here is the reference manual on array indexing, which is done with `[`:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Array-indexing

Comment: +1 though note that `,Code` is only valid because the variable was created independent of the data frame. (If `Code` wasn't an object in the environment, but was simply a column name, this code wouldn't work -- though only a tiny modification would be required.)

Comment: Like @Hugh said, this wouldn't work for the real data set, not to mentions that both the answers here were already provided in the comments long ago.

Comment: Yes, thanks for simplifying.  I must use the [ operator more!

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can try this:

```
 Key = c(1,2,3,4,5)
Code = c("X348","I605","B777","I609","F123")
df1 <- data.frame(Key, Code)
toRemove<-grep("^I60", df1$Code)
df2 <- df1[-toRemove,]
```

Comment: JFY, using `which(grepl)` is the same as just using `grep`

Comment: This answer gives the correct answer but should not be accepted because it is unnecessarily complicated.